# Launching a Stripe checkout pop-up after validating a WTForm

Tags: python, flask, stripe-payments, flask-wtforms

I have a super simple flask form for a `service` that I'm trying to integrate with the Stripe API:

```
from flask_wtf import FlaskForm
import wtforms as wtf

class ServiceForm(FlaskForm):
    name = wtf.StringField('The service name')
    submit_ = wtf.SubmitField('Submit >')
```

I'm serving this form along with my stripe key as follows:

```
@app.route('/index', methods=['GET'])
def index() -> str:
    form = ServiceForm()
    render_template('index.html', form=form, key='some stripe key',
                    service='some service', service_price=2500)
```

and the `index.html` file looks like this:

```
<form id="service-form" action="{{ url_for('pay_for_service', service=service) }}" method="POST" novalidate>
  {{ form.csrf_token }}
  {{ form.name }}
  {{ form.submit_(class_="some-button" id="service-form-submit-button") }}
  <script
    src="https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js"
    class="stripe-button"
    data-key="{{ key }}"
    data-amount="{{ service_price }}"
    data-locale="auto">
  </script>
</form>
```

The action of this form points to the following route:

```
@app.route('/pay+for+service/<string:service>', methods=['POST'])
def pay_for_service(service: str) -> str:
  form = ServiceForm()
  if form.validate_on_submit():
      # ... do some validation
      # now launch the Stripe dialog box to input credit card details.
```

which I'll use to validate the form submission before the Stripe payment dialog box is launched.

Basically, I want the `stripe-button` in the script to be embedded in the `form.submit_` button, which has a custom `some-button` class. Then I want the Stripe payment pop-up to show after I've validated the form. **How do I do this please? I think it's pretty easy but been scratching my head for ages!**

Thanks for any help, and stay safe :-)

Answer (score 1):

It's most easily done with an ajax call. Set the button action to call "submit_form" which will be:

```
function submit_form(Elem) {
  $.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: "{{ url_for('pay_for_service', service=service) }}",
  data: $("#service-form").serialize(),
  success: function(data) {
        if (data['status'] == 'success') {
          // call stripe
        } else {
            alert(data['data']['message'])
        };
    }
  });
}
```

You won't need two view functions, a single one will do:

```
@app.route('/index', methods=['GET'])
def index() -> str:
    form = ServiceForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        return json.dumps({'status': 'success', 'data': {'message': 'ok'}})
    elif request.method == 'POST':
        message = str(form.errors)
        return json.dumps({'status': 'fail', 'data': {'message': message }})
    render_template('index.html', form=form, key='some stripe key',
                    service='some service', service_price=2500)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for this.. Would you mind elaborating on the "// call stripe" comment, please?

Comment: You'll need to hide the Stripe payment until you're ready to display it. So, either found out what the element ID is and on document load (window loading) have javascript hide it: `document.getElementById('payment-form').style.display="none"` or wrap the element in a div with an ID you specify and a style of hidden by default. Once the form is validated, issue: `document.getElementById('payment-form').style.display = "block"`

Comment: Awesome -- I'll give that a go.. I didn't realise the Stripe form was a separate form, I though it need to be linked to the one that I was submitting ... Is this the correct thinking, i.e. you can have two forms on the page?

Comment: I haven't fully used Stripe but when I was working on a Django project it looked like Stripe was making an ajax call (rather than posting a form). I know Authorize.net payment gateway works this way. You fill in the CC info, press submit, and then it does an ajax call to Authorize, gets the response and then submits the form with a token to look up that transaction. So, you end up with an empty payment form but a token to use for the next part of your logic. I assume Stripe is similar, there's only so many ways to maintain PCI compliance without full blown PCI logic.

Comment: @alex_lewis don't forget to accept this as the answer if it helped. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible with the "simple" integration approach. It's possible to run your own validation and trigger the Legacy Checkout modal programmatically using the "custom" integration approach, as seen in [this example](https://jsfiddle.net/osrLsc8m/).

```
var handler = StripeCheckout.configure({ ... })
// later ...
handler.open({...})
```

However, note that this is all using an old deprecated version of Checkout. You should strongly consider using the [new Checkout](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/checkout). Among other significant advantages, you can to any validation you like [server-side before creating the checkout session](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/checkout/accept-a-payment#create-checkout-session).

Comment: Could you please give an example of using the new checkout version? I can't get the the links working that you reccomended

Comment: What do you mean you can't get the links working? This is a complete guide for setting up subscriptions using Checkout: https://stripe.com/docs/payments/checkout/set-up-a-subscription

If you want to see a complete integration, there is a sample repository here is one doing subscriptions with Checkout: https://github.com/stripe-samples/checkout-single-subscription